# Which widget can be used to display the amount spent in Android app?

Tags: android-layout

I am a newbie trying my hand in android app development.Currently,I'm trying to develop a simple app to track my expenses. But I'm stuck in deciding which widget exactly to be used to display the rate of expense.

I would like to show something like in android task manager showing RAM usage.
Would using a progress bar work in this context and how? Please help! Thank you

Comment: good question...but have you tried anything...*Would using a progress bar work in this context*?

Comment: @user3320018 not yet... but il try now

Comment: @Anjali You can find tutorials using Google https://www.google.co.in/#q=android+progress+bar+example